# How to access corresponding directories (in parallel directory structures like `src` and `test`)?

Tags: bash, directory, symlink, cd, isomorphism

A simple hack in `.bashrc` to switch between them:

```
c-() {
  cd $(pwd | sed 's/test/src/; t; s/src/test/');
}
```

Named `c-`, for `cd -`. Try to substiture `test` with `src` in the path, `t` means exit on success. Else try converse. If nothing matches, has no effect. [Incorrect if `src` or `test` appear elsewhere in the path].

But... I'd really something that could be used generally as part of a path - like a symbolic link, so it works for `vi`/`emacs`, `mv`, `rm`, `ls` etc, not just `cd`. It would be as if: from the `src` tree, `t` links to the corresponding directory in the `test` tree (and back link `s`), to use like:

```
vi mysrc t/mytest
```

Of course, an *actual* symbolic link does this. Could manually add as needed (or recursively do all) - but seems messy. Another way is `t` as a script or function:

```
vi mysrc `t`/mytest
vi mysrc $(t)/mytest
```

But I'd (lazily) like to avoid the ``` `` ``` or `$()`, and somehow make `t` dynamically act as a symbolic link... need to parse and modify the command line?

Or maybe the whole idea is dangerous and stupid, having wild effects whenever you use `t`? It would have to be context sensitive in the command line (i.e. when a path/filename/argument is needed, and be at the head). Or maybe a weird kind of auto-complete?

Can we do this? (Should we do this?)

Comment: What's messy about using symbolic links?

Comment: @suspectus For development, I like my directories really bare (uncluttered), it helps me focus, in a coupling/cohesion kind of a way - at least for the very complex layered stuff I'm working on at the moment. e.g. I find even 4 files a bit confusing/distracting if they're not all part of the same thing in the same way. Don't judge me. But maybe you're right, symbolic links are even a different colour after all.

Comment: I also don't want git to track them - a minor mess.

Comment: ok so just add links to `.gitignore`

Comment: @suspectus that's the "minor mess", now it's part of the project. Another problem is, if you cd to a link, that's now in the path - gets deeper if you follow another symlink back. This also has a solution: use `cd -P` (for physical, not symbolic), but another minor mess.

Comment: If you find `cd` commands too taxing, maybe use an IDE?

Comment: @suspectus lol I feel like you are making fun of me just because I am le tired. Though of course you're right, an IDE would ease all of this. OTOH I could config `^t` in .inputrc to output \`t\` - ah, that's the kind of thing I've been thinking of, with auto replacement in the commandline.